# Mysql on Ubuntu repeatedly changes my empty root password so I can't access the server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm getting pretty desperate because of mysql...
Two months ago I started working on Ubuntu and we have a project at university, where we have to maintain a webapplication written in Java with the Spring Framework. For this I needed to set up a local mysql server and for the application to work, the root password had to be empty...

However the problems started right away. Although I left the password empty on installation, the app threw an error because it couldn't connect to the mysql server. After trying all commandline password change methods on the internet I finally got it to work somehow.

But after a couple of day the same error occured again!! It seems like somehow mysql has changed the password on its own, maybe because it doesn't like it to be empty. The second time I had a pretty hard time resetting it, because nothing would work. For example if I tried to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

I simply got:

```
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.16, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Using --force didn't help either. So in the end I settled for completely removing mysql and installing it again. This time I would provide a valid password and then install the mysql workbench and change the password in the workbench to empty.

This worked for about three weeks, but now I can't access the server again!!! I don't want to reinstall mysql twice a month!

I don't think the problem is with the application, because on my windows laptop I don't have any problems.

On Ubuntu im using Mysql-Server-5.7.

I hope someone can help me I'm really desperate...

Comment: Could it be that your application that requires a blank root password is changing it? Like maybe that's why it requires it to be blank? I've never heard of an OS or MySQL itself changing a blank root password all on it's own. What would be the point since it would completely render the MySQL instance 100% unusable since it would lock you out. Perhaps... perhaps someone that can ping that server is changing it just to mess with you (or more nefarious reasons). I think the real problem is that you are setting your root password to be blank.

Comment: Also, you can reset the root password without reinstalling the server. [see here](https://debian-administration.org/article/442/Resetting_a_forgotten_MySQL_root_password)

Comment: No as i said I dont think it's because of the application, because on Windows it works fine. I also don't think someone is playing with me...

Comment: I know i can change the Password in other ways but they wouldn't work with a blank Password. Through workbench it works every time. 
Also maybe I should mention that I use a dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10